How to get next page of Tumblr posts using JS & Ajax
For a React project using vanilla js, I'm scraping my Tumlbr blog to retrieve all photo posts and imbed them into a 'blog' page on my application. I'm using ajax to do this, since the tumblr.js package doesn't support in-browser calls and my back-end is in Rails. Here's the working code to get the first 20 posts on page 1 of my tumblr:
export const getPosts = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    $.ajax({
      url:"https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/somewhatadrift.tumblr.com/posts/photo?...&api_key=...",
      type: "GET",
      context: this,
      success: function(result) {
        let posts = result.response.posts.filter(post => post.type === 'photo');
        dispatch(setPosts(posts));
      }
    });
  }
}

The result from this call looks like 
The Tumlbr API documentation states that total_posts is "The total number of post available for this request, useful for paginating through results" but doesn't give a clear example on how to do this.

In Tumblr you have access to some url params. Offset and limit. Limit is defaulted to 20 posts, but you can tweak this to a maximum of 50. So you just need a loop where you increment the offset while it is less than the total posts I can write it up fully in an answer if you like but I am pretty sure you will get the gist of it. let limit; const retrieveMore = (offset) => {  ...  if (total_posts >= offset && posts.length !== 0) { retrieveMore(offset + limit);

Hi, do you mind writing a total post out? My implementation isn't working, and I want to make sure I understand. Thanks!

OK. I will try my best to answer.
You need something along these lines.
export const getPosts = () => {
    let limit = 20; // set this to any value you want up to 50. 
    const retrieveMore = function (offset) {
        $.ajax({
            url: `https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/somewhatadrift.tumblr.com/posts?limit=${limit}&offset=${offset}`,,
            success(result) {
                let i = 0;
                const totalPosts = result.response.total_posts;
                const postLength = result.response.posts.length;
                while (i < postLength) {
                    // do your magic here
                    dispatch(setPosts(posts)); // not sure if this will rerender using React. Usually I would push this to an array. 
                    i++;
                }
                if (totalPosts >= offset && postLength !== 0) {
                    retrieveMore(offset + limit);
                }
            }
        });
    };
    retrieveMore(0);
};

I will try and break some of it down.
let limit = 20

You can set this to any value up to 50 (but we will loop over it until we reach the total posts count). In fact if you set it as 20 it is the default, you don't actually need it as a param in the url.
url: `https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/somewhatadrift.tumblr.com/posts?limit=${limit}&offset=${offset}`,

We convert this to a template literal using backticks so we can insert a dynamic variable each time the loop increments.
Then we create a counter using i.
While i is less than the postLength then we extract our posts (or apply whatever logic you want and then increment i using i++.
We then check if the totalPosts count is greater or equal to the offset, if it isn't there are more posts to return, and we run the function again but increment the counter. retrieveMore(offset + limit);
The first time this runs we use retrieveMore(0) on the next run the counter will get incremented until we hit the condition that checks if the total number of posts is greater than the offset plus the limit. And at that point we know there are no more posts to retrieve.
EDIT
At each iteration of the loop you can console log offset, i and other variables to see the looping.
Hope this helps.
